# How do I launch miraclecast after installation?

Tags: software-installation, launcher

I have successfully installed miracle cast on my Ubuntu 16.04 but I don't know how to launch the app. I also searched in the app drawer but didn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to use it as sink.

1. shutdown wpa_supplicant and NetworkManager

> ```
> $ systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
> $ systemctl stop wpa_supplicant.service
> ```

2. launch wifi daemon

> ```
> $ sudo miracle-wifid &
> ```

3. launch sink control (your network card will be detected. here 3)

> ```
> $ sudo miracle-sinkctl 
> [ADD]  Link: 3
> ```

4. run WiFi Display on link:

> ```
> run 3
> ```

5. Pair your machine with other miracast device (mirroring)
6. See your screen device on this machine

Steps to use it as peer

1. Repeat steps 1 and 2 from "use as sink"
2. launch wifi control

> ```
> $ sudo miracle-wifictl
> ```

3. Enable visibility for other devices
4. Locate them using scanning

> ```
> p2p-scan
> ```

Please see [this](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast#steps-to-use-it-as-sink) and [this](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast#steps-to-use-it-as-peer) their github page.